# Spring not restoring tomcat persistent sessions to session registry after restart?

Tags: java, tomcat, spring-security

I'm using Tomcat 6.2 and Spring MVC 2.5. I've noticed that, whilst a user is logged in I can restart Tomcat and the user is able to continue browsing without re-authenticating. This appears to be coming from Tomcat's ability to persist sessions across restarts.

It appears, however, that these persisted sessions do not make it back into the Spring session registry. When retrieving a user's session information from the session registry before the restart I get back information. Post a restart though the sesssion registry has no information on the user.

Have I missed some configuration that would allow Spring to restore these persisted Tomcat sessions after a restart? Failing that, is there a way to kick a user out of the web application without calling sessionInformation.expireNow()?

Comment: what is this "session registry" you're referring to? Spring uses tomcat's session memory, it doesn't have its own.

Comment: The session registry I am referring to is the internal Spring Security class (SessionRegistryImpl) that is populate on user login with the the user's session information. On a tomcat restart it seems that tomcat is able to persist and restore the user's session and Spring somehow accepts that as valid session but there is not data in Spring's session registry regarding that session.

Comment: Ah, you're talking about Spring Security? That's completely distinct and separate from Spring MVC.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this configuration:

```
<bean id="filterInvocationInterceptor" class="org.acegisecurity.intercept.web.FilterSecurityInterceptor">
    ...
    <property name="alwaysReauthenticate" value="true"/>
</bean>
```

Comment: Thanks, that sounds promising. Will there be a performance impact if your authentication store is, say, a database?

Comment: @rodrigoap Can you elaborate a bit about what the configuration represents? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Are the objects, you want persisted and then restored from the session, serializable?

Comment: I did initially get serialization exceptions and have fixed them. Fixing them didn't seem to make resolve this though.