# spring security java based config after tomcat restart

Tags: java, spring-mvc, tomcat, spring-security

I'm trying to learn spring and I'm having problems with my security user, from spring-security. After restarting tomcat, It´s leaving my current loged user as null when I use the

```
<security:authentication property="principal.username"/>
```

tag.


my spring-security config is simple

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvcSecurity
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

@Autowired
private CustomUserDetailsService customUserDetailsService;

@Override
protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder registry)throws Exception{
    Md5PasswordEncoder e = new Md5PasswordEncoder();
    registry.userDetailsService(customUserDetailsService).passwordEncoder(e);
}

@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http.authorizeRequests()
        .antMatchers("/resources/**").permitAll()
        .antMatchers("/webjars/**").permitAll()
        .antMatchers("/admin/**").hasAuthority("ADMIN")
        .anyRequest().authenticated()
        .and().formLogin().loginPage("/login").permitAll()
        .and().logout().permitAll();
}
}
```

I've seen [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1587423/spring-not-restoring-tomcat-persistent-sessions-to-session-registry-after-restar), but it makes me think that I must change a lot of things in my security config
**EDIT:**
Here's my SecurityUser

```
public class SecurityUser extends Usuario implements UserDetails {

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

public SecurityUser(Usuario usuario) {
    this.setEliminado(usuario.isEliminado());
    this.setFechaCreacion(usuario.getFechaCreacion());
    this.setPassword(usuario.getPassword());
    this.setRoles(usuario.getRoles());
    this.setUltimaModificacion(usuario.getUltimaModificacion());
    this.setUsername(usuario.getUsername());
}

@Override
public Collection<? extends GrantedAuthority> getAuthorities() {
    Collection<GrantedAuthority> authorities = new ArrayList<GrantedAuthority>();
    Set<Rol> userRoles = this.getRoles();
    if (userRoles != null) {
        for (Rol role : userRoles) {
            SimpleGrantedAuthority authority = new SimpleGrantedAuthority(role.getDescripcion());
            authorities.add(authority);
        }
    }
    return authorities;
}

@Override
public String getPassword(){
    return super.getPassword();
}

@Override
public String getUsername(){
    return super.getUsername();
}

@Override
public boolean isAccountNonExpired() {
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean isAccountNonLocked() {
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean isCredentialsNonExpired() {
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean isEnabled() {
    return true;
}

}
```

And here's my UserServiceDetalis:

```
@Component
public class CustomUserDetailsService implements UserDetailsService{
@Autowired
private UsuarioRepository usuarioService;

@Override
public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String username)  throws UsernameNotFoundException {
    Usuario u = usuarioService.findByUsername(username);
    if(u==null)
        throw new UsernameNotFoundException("No se ha encontrado el usuario "+username);
    return new SecurityUser(u);
  }

}
```

I'm using java based config so I don't have a web.xml file.
whatever you need to see, please tell me and I'll post it

Thanks for your help!!!
PD: sorry for my English :P

Comment: How does your principal/UserDetails class look like?

Comment: hello @holmis83 take a look to the edit, is that what you want to see?, and I want to thank you for your help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `Usuario` class is not included, but my guess is that it doesn't implement `java.io.Serializable`. When Tomcat is restarted, the sessions are serialized to be stored on disk. Only fields within a class implementing `Serializable` are written by default (even if subclass implements `Serializable`). So your class declaration should look something like:

```java
public class Usuario implements Serializable
```

Also make sure your username field is *not* marked `transient`.

Comment: It works... I thought that when the SecurityUser implemented the UserDetails, was enough to serialize the security object, I've got another question about serialization, do you think that I should implement serializable on all my Entities?... and a Big Thanks!!!!

Comment: @dTobon I would say YAGNI.