# Enable session persistence with Spring Boot and embedded Tomcat

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, tomcat, spring-boot

I'm developing an application with Spring Boot and Spring Security by starting the Application class in Eclipse with an embedded Tomcat. Every time I restart the server, my session disappears and I have to log in again which becomes quite annoying.

Is it possible to persist the sessions between server restarts?

I saw this other question on Stackoverflow where someone asks the opposite, which makes me think that this should actually work out-of-the-box:

[How to disable Tomact session persistence in Spring Boot via Manager pathname?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27130157/how-to-disable-tomact-session-persistence-in-spring-boot-via-manager-pathname)

I'm running Spring Boot 1.2.1 with Gradle.

btw, I know about Spring Loaded, but sometimes a server restart is unavoidable.

Comment: Did you check these posts : [JDBC Session Persistence](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20507749/how-can-i-make-the-spring-security-stores-the-http-session-in-database-so-i-can?answertab=active#tab-top) & [FilterInvocationInterceptor Bean](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1587423/spring-not-restoring-tomcat-persistent-sessions-to-session-registry-after-restar?answertab=active#tab-top) ?

Comment: also make sure everything you put in session is Serializable

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I just figured this out myself. Everytime the application is started, Spring generates a new random temporary directory in `/tmp` for Tomcat's base directory (e.g. `/tmp/tomcat.5990562997404648887.8080`). Since it uses a different folder on each start, Tomcat has no way to restore the session.

This can be worked around by setting your own base directory with `server.tomcat.basedir=/tmp`. However, I don't consider this a fix since it requires setting an operating system specific directory, so I opened a bug about this: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/2490

Answer (score 18):

According to the Spring this will be fixed in **1.3.0.M2** and eventually in **1.3.0.RELEASE**

Then all you got to do is add the following line to your `application.properties` file.

```
server.session.persistent=true
```

In recent Spring versions this has been deprecated and replaced by:

```
server.servlet.session.persistent=true
```

Reference https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/2490

> Update Tomcat, Jetty and Undertow to serialize session data when the
>   application is stopped and load it again when the application
>   restarts.
>
> Persistent session are opt-in; either by setting `persistentSession`
>   on the ConfigurableEmbeddedServletContainer or by using the property
>   `server.session.persistent=true`.
>
> Fixes gh-2490

Comment: Yup, this is now fixed - also worth mentioning that devtools enables this flag by default.

Comment: I have this and I still lose my Spring Authentications after server restart. :(

Comment: If you have spring security enabled, make sure any custom objects that you put into SecurityContext is serializable, otherwise the restored session would be considered invalid by spring security.

Comment: For me also needed this configuration:
`server.servlet.session.storeDir=/tmp/my-app-sessions`

Answer (score 4):

I solved it by using Redis to persist sessions info.

All you need to do is specify a few options in application.yml file:

```
server:
  servlet:
    session:
      persistent: true
spring:
  session:
    store-type: redis
  redis:
    host: localhost
    port: 6379
 ...
```

build.gradle

```
    plugins {
       id 'java'
       id 'io.spring.dependency-management' version '1.0.6.RELEASE'
       id 'org.springframework.boot' version '2.1.3.RELEASE'
   }
    ...
    // Spring Framework
    compile(
            'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web',
            'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa',
            'org.springframework.data:spring-data-redis',
            'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-security'
    )
    ...
```

Works perfect with Spring Boot 2.1.3

Comment: hallo why do you need jpa ?

Comment: @Tama For session persistence you don't need, it's a sample file from my project. I need it to have database support.

Comment: The spring-boot magic never ceases to amaze me!